# Map zooming out of svg in IE9

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have a map and whenever I zoom in on the map, the map gets bigger (zoom works correctly), but the map goes beyond the edges of the SVG, and hence covers up other features of my webpage. This only happens in IE9. In chrome, the maps always stays inside of the SVG whenever I zoom in on it. Has anyone else had this problem and suggest a route to take to solve it? I would like to keep the map inside of the SVG.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the IE9. The IE9 doesn't respect the default SVG overflow mode, which must be hidden.

You can correct this behaviour if you manually set `style = "overflow:hidden"`, either in the outermost SVG element or in a surrounding `<DIV>` element, for example

```
<div style = "overflow:hidden"> <svg> ... </svg> </div>
```

of in JavaScript

```
divElement.setAttribute("style", "overflow:hidden");
```

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971320/svg-image-is-not-cropped-in-ie9) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642815/svg-draws-outside-canvas-boundary-in-internet-explorer-9).